# Maximum Splin/ Fit for data?

Tags: python, statistics, curve-fitting, data-fitting

Lets assume I have a some noisy data d(x), like a function f(x) with some noise g(x) which is strongly dependent on x, with d(x) = f(x) + g(x). Is there a clean way to fit or use a spline, lets call it s(x), such that

- s(x) is smooth
- s(x) > d(x) for almost all x
- |s(x) - d(x)| < constant

My idea was to use some filter like Savitzky-Golay to smooth the data and then fit only the maximal part of the result, but actually this method is not very successful.

Comment: My advice would be to model f and g separately and then construct s from f + (upper tail quantile of g). You'll probably get more traction for this question on stats.stackexchange.com or physics.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Could you give examples for f and g, please?